# How to remove arrows if there are second-level menu items in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, css-shapes

Please check out the side menu on this page:

http://exide24.pl/przydatne-informacje/

As you can see, there are annoying little arrows in the first-level menu items that appear if there are second-level menu items. How can I remove them? It cannot be CSS since I created a class just for this menu. It cannot be JavaScript (I think) because of the same reason. I think it is something WordPress-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your **css file** Line 678 you have this:

```
.arrow:after {
color: #666666;
content: " »";
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
position: absolute;
right: 2px;
top: 0;
}
```

Change it to:

```
.arrow:after {
color: #666666;
content: " ";
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
position: absolute;
right: 2px;
top: 0;
}
```

Or you can remove (delete) that property altogether.